# JavaScript to Submit Page After 30 Seconds

Tags: javascript, scripting, form-submit

I am looking for a JavaScript to submit a page after 30 seconds from when the page is loaded.  Does jQuery offer this functionality or does someone have regular javascript for this?  Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Using setTimeout you can achieve this by having a callback function which can submit a form for you (I presume that is what you mean by saying to 'submit a page')

```
    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.myform.submit();
    }, 30000);
    </script>
```

That will submit the form with the name 'myform' after 30 seconds the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You submit a *form*, not a page. You don't need jQuery to do that.

```
<form id="foo">
    // etc.
</form>

<script>
    function doSubmit() { document.getElementById('foo').submit(); }
    setTimeout(doSubmit, 30000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function.